# problems with ruby gem ns-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build an app in Rails. For my app I need to use the ns-api (dutch railways) in order to get from them the trains timetables. It exists as a gem (https://github.com/zilverline/ns-api) I use the bundler and I get the message that all the gems are ok, but when I am trying to create a controller it gives me the error that it does not recognise NSclient . This happens also when I use "`require 'ns_client'`" in my controller or in my configuration file. I think that although the bundler seems to work , the gem is not compatible with my Rails (ver 5.0.0) or my ruby version. Any way that I could solve this ?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you get?

Comment: It looks like it's `NSClient`, with capitalized C.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but i kind of cheated and used a different gem :)

Comment: Well, next time pay attention to the case of the characters in the class/module names :)